# How can I completely reset android samsung galaxy s 4g?

Tags: factory-reset

My phone has gotten extremely slow, and the GPS no longer seems to function which is the main reason I got the phone.

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S 4G from T-Mobile.

Is it possible to reset it completely? I read several reset guides, and they said to hold the volume down + power and volume up + power but neither of those worked.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I don't have that particular model, but every Android phone I've owned has had a "Factory Data Reset" option.  On my Nexus S, it's under Settings/Privacy.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following USSD codes to do what you want:

```
*#7780#        Factory Reset  
*2767*3855#    Full Factory Reset  
*#*#7780#*#    Factory data reset
```

Source: [XDA Developers Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1953506)

A full factory reset is also known as a hard reset. It deletes all of your user data, firmware settings, and wipes your SD Card as well. Factory resets do not wipe the SD Card. Basically, a hard reset leaves nothing but the last ROM flashed. This is probably what you want.

[Factory Reset vs. Hard Reset](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=14766040)